# Info Bip Sms Sending issue

Tags: customer, api, notification, infobip

I am using the Info bip for sending SMS notifications to customer by Kakoa. I am facing this issue. I tried a lot but I am still facing this issue.

AnyOne help me to get rid of this.

[image]

Comment: For the trial account, with 5 registered numbers, it is working. Upon upgrading ang bought credits, i'm receiving that kind of error. Did you successfully fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are receiving an error message when attempting to send SMS notifications using Info bip and Kakao.

The error message "Account not provisioned for global one or two way sms (code 592). REASON: REJECTED_ROUTE_NOT_AVAILABLE" suggests that your account is not configured to send SMS messages globally, or that there is no available route for sending the message.

To resolve this issue, you will need to contact Info bip or Kakao and ask them to enable global SMS support for your account, or to troubleshoot the issue with the available routes. They may need to check your account settings and verify that you have the necessary permissions and configurations in place to send SMS messages globally.

If you are unable to resolve the issue with Info bip or Kakao, you may want to consider using a different SMS service provider that offers global SMS support and has a reliable route for sending messages. There are many SMS service providers available that offer this type of service, so you may want to do some research and compare different options to find the one that best meets your needs.

Comment: But Sms Text is sent globaly this issue is still in the Kakoa Text